# csrf token leading to Session Destroy after every request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, token, csrf

**Usage which works fine**

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

  $.ajax({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
   // My Code...
  });
```

The  above method works fine for all my data related requests...

**Method which Does NOT work and why**

I have a link which is used to redirect to my Website. The link tracks User IP, Date and from which platform he's from (Facebook, Twitter etc)
So My code is

Web.php

```
Route::get('/SOME_LINK/{IP}/{PLATFORM}', [StoreDataController::class, 'storeData']);
```

Controller

```
public function storeData(Request $request)
{
    DB::connection('myDB')->select("INSERT INTO TRAFFIC ...");
}
```

I use Username/Password to login to a panel where i can view my table data. I set session which keeps me logged in. But every time a user clicks on the link, i have to relogin again because my session is destroyed.

My guess is that its because of the csrf mismatch but I'm not sure on what to do here.
Any Suggestions to solve this issue?

Comment: What does this mean I use a sessions to login to view the table data and every time a user clicks on the link,?

Comment: Look at the updated question. Apologies for the language @Jaymin

Comment: '_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')

Comment: The csrf field's name should be _token:

Answer (score 0):

and put it in the request body, not in the headers, like this:

```
$.post(
    '/url',
    {
        '_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
        ...

    }
).done(function(data ){...});
```

Comment: I don't use ajax for uploading data. As mentioned in the second part of the question, i go from route to controllers and insert the data and redirect to my website.

Comment: I put the first part in the question just to show that Ajax works fine but the method which i mentioned is not